# Reading 2d array of character in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, 2d, readfile

I have a text file in the form.

```
8
* 0 * * * 0 0 0
0 * 0 * 0 * * *
0 0 * 0 * 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 * 0 0 0
0 * * 0 0 0 * 0
0 0 0 0 * 0 0 *
* 0 * 0 0 0 * 0
0 0 0 0 * 0 0 0
```

where 8 tells me the number of rows and columns in the file to read, followed by 8*8 rows and columns of char. Here is the code to read 8*8 array. I don't know how to separately read integer 8 first and the run my this code.

```
char[][] result = File.ReadAllLines("hotel_in2.txt")
   .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(i => char.Parse(i)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Kindly suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: Is there going to be anything else in the file? If not, do you really *need* that first line?

Comment: I don't know C# so well so won't try to answer, but surely it uses file streams.  Open the file, read the first line, then read all subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) method to skip first element of array:

```
char[][] result = File.ReadAllLines("hotel_in2.txt").Skip(1)
   .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(i => char.Parse(i)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Skip` to bypass the first line since your code doesn't seem to require it.

```
char[][] result = File.ReadAllLines("hotel_in2.txt")
   .Skip(1)
   .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(i => char.Parse(i)).ToArray())
   .ToArray();
```

Alternatively you can assign the `ReadAllLines` to a variable and use `First` to get that value.

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines("hotel_in2.txt");
int size = int.Parse(file.First());
char[][] result = file
   .Skip(1)
   .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(i => char.Parse(i)).ToArray())
   .ToArray();
```